# how to create an slideshow without transition and inline styles adding to html? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

> UPDATE: I have updated this post more than 5 times but still couldn't
>   get appropriate answer , I'll appreciate if you could read my question
>   carefully and answer it <3

I want to create **slideshow** just like `bwin's mobile version website`. I started to analyse how it works. but it works weird, if you use inspect element in google chrome or any browsers you can see the slideshow works **without** any `inline styles added dynamically`.

in every slideshows that I've seen before there was inline styles that they added to HTML tags in a specific time interval. in this case I can't see any inline styles that add to tags but it works like a charm. I checked the `CSS` files for the `keyframe` property and there was nothing and of curse they don't use `transition` too.

for more information is good to say they use angular as their front-end framework.

**Note:** please open the mobile version of the website in computer to see what is going on !

The address is : `https://sports.m.bwin.com/en/sports`

I'll be appreciated if you tell how does the bwin's slideshow works? and how to create this slideshow?

thanks a lot <3

> UPDATE: Special thanks to Sergiu Paraschiv that he figured out google
>   chrome's dev tools doesn't show inline changes for translateX property
>   of DOM Shadows , he tested the bwin's mobile version with his Safari
>   in his Mac machine and he captured screenshot "[imgur.com/a/Php4EhB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sSWl.jpg)" ,
>   so you can see the inline changes in Safari browser of Mac OS . Why
>   google chrome or firefox doesn't show the changes of inline translateX
>   property of the DOM Shadows?

Comment: Could be using a canvas?

Comment: For some reason Chrome does not display the inline `translateX` styles. If I open this page with Safari on my Mac I can see these inline styles being changed while animating. I think this might have to do with shadow DOM and Chrome dev tools probably ignores changes done that way.

Comment: @MrZach thank you for replying . unfortunately it's not canvas .

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv thanks a lot , that is a very good point . do you use the latest version of **Safari** in your **Mac** machine?

Comment: I guess so. I'm on Mojave with Safari 12.0 (14606.1.36.1.9). Also as far as I can tell from the minified code they're using https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationPlayer

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv unfortunately I have windows machine and I can't test the things that you mentioned . anyway thanks a lot <3.

Comment: Maybe try chromium? They might have fixed this. I know around v62 they removed "experimental support for shadow DOM v0" and replaced it with a "v1" implementation and that's when the "Display shadow DOM" checkbox in dev tools settings got removed too.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv thanks , I'm now downloading the Chromium browser , I will let know after testing it .

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv still same problem after installing Chromium, would you me tell which elements with what class name changes their inline styles in your safari browser?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Php4EhB - that's what I see in Safari.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv thanks a lot I've never seen that before in any browser in my windows machine . it's really weird , anyway do you have any idea how to create this slideshow?